# SQL CE Insert error

Tags: c#, sql, mobile

I'm creating an application for PDA (WM 6).
When I try to insert data in the database always encounter this error.

**Error:**

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 100,Token in error = ) ]

**Code :**

```
public static bool InsertPedido(int id, int Vim, DateTime date, int quantidade)
{
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=" + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + @"\\DataPedido.sdf; Password =SUPER2000PED;");

    conn.Open();
    try
    {
        SqlCeCommand comando = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO Pedido([IDLayout], [Vim], [Data], [Quantidade])VALUES(@IDLayout,@Vim,@Data,@Quantidade))", conn);

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDLatout", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vim", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Vim;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = date;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantidade", SqlDbType.Int).Value = quantidade;

        int row = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much closing parenthesis

```
    SqlCeCommand comando = new SqlCeCommand(@"INSERT INTO Pedido
      ([IDLayout], [Vim], [Data], [Quantidade])
      VALUES(@IDLayout,@Vim,@Data,@Quantidade)", conn);
                                             ^^^
```

Comment: Fastest gun of the west.. `+1`